# Neo4J Admin visualization as a part of Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j, graph-visualization

I am working on a small internally deployed Rails Application in my organisation with Neo4J as persistence layer.

I want to allow users to be able to visually see the Data stored in the Database Browser provided by Neo4J and interact with it. ( Security is not a concern )

However I want to keep the experience seamless and provide the visualisation tool as a part of my web application.

Is there a work around for it?

Comment: this may help https://github.com/andreasronge/neo4j-admin

Comment: The gem starts an admin interface in 'localhost:7474'. If my rails app is running on 'localhost:3000', I want the visualisation to be accessed as say 'localhost:3000/visualise'.

Comment: you can change the port on virtualhosts and routes